# what does ⊕ and ⊖ mean in regard to matrix/vector operations?

Tags: matrices, vectors

In the context of simultaneous calibration in robotics with a differential drive robot a particular formula was shown to me.

Regarding the operations on this vectors, what does the symbols ⊕ and ⊖ mean?

[Simultaneous Calibration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEHbh.png)

Comment: They are defined in the picture you attached.

Comment: Oh my, you are right. How can I flag your comment as the right answer :)?

Comment: I'll write a short answer.

Comment: I wrote it as an answer. You can also delete your question if you want. Your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't look like standard operations to me, but they are explicitly defined in the picture you attached.

Comment: Thanks, that was very useful :)